# ¿Por qué me cambia valores anteriores del hashmap en cada vuelta de bucle?

Tags: java, hashmap

Estoy practicando con hashmaps y bucles y no entiendo por qué me cambia los valores anteriores en cada vuelta de bucle.
Este es el código; todo va bien hasta que al final imprime el último valor de `i`.

```
    HashMap y = new HashMap();
    HashMap z = new HashMap();
    String letra[] = {"a","b","c"};
    String panorama[] = {"hola","adios","navidad"};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< 3; j++) {
        y.put(letra[j], i);
      }
        z.put(panorama[i],y);
    }
    System.out.println(z);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. Además, pon en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando.

Comment: Buenas, Andrew, bienvenido al sitio. No está claro cual es tu problema. Efectivamente para cada letra está almacenando el máximo valor de i, lo que tú has implementado en tu código. En la primera iteración del bucle exterior lo único que haces es asignar a todas las claves el valor 0; en la siguiente a esas mismas claves le asignas el valor 1; en la última a todas las claves le asignas el valor 2. Todas esas asignaciones consecutivas sobre las mismas claves, tienen el mismo sentido que ejecutar esto `int k = 0; k = 1; k = 2; k = 3; System.out.print(k);` Este código simple escribirá `3` siempre

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el problema. Tampoco explicas qué exactamente debe hacer tu código. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: gracias rubioric , pensaba que se podía poner en un diccionario claves iguales con diferentes valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo creas un único *HashMap* `y`, así que en cada iteración estás sobreescribiendo los datos del mismo *HashMap* en el bucle interior y asignándolo para cada clave de `z`.

Si haces `z.get("hola") == z.get("adios")` te devolverá *true* porque los dos valores te devuelven el mismo objeto.

Simplemente, en cada iteración del bucle exterior asigna a `y` una nueva instancia de *HashMap* para que no quede afectada la instancia que rellenaste en la iteración anterior.

Comment: Vale ya lo entiendo Juan, yo pensaba que en un diccionario se podía almacenar la misma clave con diferentes resultados. Gracias x la respuesta xcierto.